# How to return a variable outside axios?

Tags: javascript, axios

I'm trying to map the data to a variable by using axios response, however the variable remains empty when I return it to another function for use. The following is my code:

```
function factoryBootup() {

  var userInfo = {
    userName: "",
    prefixUrl: ""
  };

  let instance = axios.create({
    timeout: requestTimeout
  });

  instance.get(bootUrl, {
  }).then(function(response) {
    var jsonObj =  JSON.stringify(response.data);
    var a = JSON.parse(jsonObj);
    userInfo.userName = a.userInfo.userId;
    userInfo.prefixUrl = a.userInfo.urlId;
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log("Get error happens: " + error);
  });

  return userInfo;
}
```

I want to export the `userInfo` variable outside the function, but it seems not working. Can anyone helping me?

Comment: Return the whole promise from `factoryBootup` and then call `.then` on it.

Answer (score 1):

you could try it this way

```
function factoryBootup() {
    let instance = axios.create({
        timeout: requestTimeout
    });

    return instance.get(bootUrl, {});
}
```

then use the function where ever you may want to use it like this:

```
factoryBootup()
    .then(function(response) {
        var jsonObj =  JSON.stringify(response.data);
        var a = JSON.parse(jsonObj);
        //userInfo.userName = a.userInfo.userId;
        //userInfo.prefixUrl = a.userInfo.urlId;

    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Get error happens: " + error);
    });
```